# Custom Font for Phonegap using Adobe Edge

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, cordova, adobe-edge

Anyone knows if there is a way without the use of webfonts to embed font into an Adobe Edge Animate composition so that the fonts can be seen when I create a Phonegap iOS app with the html file i get from Edge Animate?

All i can find so far is custom fonts for Edge Animate that uses webfonts which means I can only add links rather then embedded directly into the file or custom fonts for Phonegap where using font-family in css but that doesn't seems to be read by Edge.

I was thinking there is some way in the edge.js file that is output where they use

```
    var fonts = {};
   fonts['londrina-shadow, sans-serif']='<script src=\"http://use.edgefonts.net/londrina-shadow:n4:all.js\"></script>';
   fonts['cabin-sketch, sans-serif']='<script src=\"http://use.edgefonts.net/cabin-sketch:n4,n7:all.js\"></script>';
   fonts['coming-soon, sans-serif']='<script src=\"http://use.edgefonts.net/coming-soon:n4:all.js\"></script>';
```

to embed webfonts. Can I do something to it to embed the fonts with a path like src:"fonts/coming-soon.ttf"

Hope there is an answer to this or is there simply no way to do this cos Adobe decide to only link webfonts and screw us up.

Answer (score 0):

Does the css work if you add that class to the div you are animating. If you save out the edge project, the open it in dreamweaver you can attach a css stylesheet. When you go back to edge and add that style it should show up in the animation.  I know this works if you want to add png's to an animation. Not sure if it will work but could. I will look into it now and see if I can figure it out.